# Using Ubuntu to create a VHD of a Windows 10 HDD

Tags: virtualization

I have a Windows 10 laptop that I dropped (make sure the zipper is closed on your backpack!).

The HDD is an SSD drive so I'm relatively confident that drive is fine. I'd like to remove it from the laptop, connect it to my Ubuntu laptop, and convert the drive to a VM.

Is this possible? If so, what would the steps be? I've only started using Ubuntu for about 3 weeks so I'm a baby ubuntu user.

I thought about creating a Windows 10 VM inside of Ubuntu and then running disk2vhd (MS Systernals utility) to build the VM but that sounds too "Inception"-esque (Movie Inception reference) and to be honest, hoping to skip that step.